# Getting only one row for a given column value

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation, proximity

The basic structure of my query is this:

- I have a `profiles` table with profile information
- I have a `locations` table with location coordinates
- I have a `location_assignment` table which just contains (profile_id, location_id) pairs

Each profile is assigned to one or more locations, and what I'm trying to do is search the profiles, and return them in order of distance to the location coordinates. My query to do so is (with only the relevant parts included) as follows:

```
SELECT *, 
      (3959*acos(cos(radians(30.292424))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-  
       radians(-97.73856))+sin(radians(30.292424))*sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance,
      `profiles`.`name` as profilename, 
      `profiles`.`profile_id` as profile_id
 FROM (`profiles`)
 JOIN `location_assignment` 
          ON `profiles`.`profile_id` =`location_assignment`.`profile_id`
 JOIN `locations` 
          ON `location_assignment`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id`
HAVING `distance` < 50
ORDER BY `distance`
LIMIT 3"
```

*(That grosstastic thing in the select line converts the lat/lng fields in the `locations` table into a distance from a given input lat/lng)*

However, my query makes profiles appear multiple times in the  results, once for each location he is assigned to. I would like each profile to appear only once, with the information for the location with the shortest distance.

My knee-jerk reaction is to use `group_by location_id`, but I want to make sure I get the location with the minimum distance to the input coordinates.

Comment: You have a `HAVING` in your code, so either you are missing a `GROUP BY` or you want a `WHERE` instead.

Comment: You may want to specify the type of joins in your select (these should be LEFT JOIN)

Comment: @Rafa: ah sorry, I removed a bunch of irrelevant other table joins (this query spans seven tables) and yes one of the things I removed is a `WHERE`. The full clause is "WHERE `procedures`.`procedure_id` = 18 AND `base_price` > 0 HAVING `distance` < 50 ORDER BY `distance`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go Longhorns!

Let's start by finding the right row in the location table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT location_id
  FROM locations
 ORDER BY your_spherical_cosine_law_distance_formula
 LIMIT 1
```

That gets you the unique location id.

Now you want to use that as a subquery to get the appropriate profiles rows.  That you do like this:

```
 SELECT whatever
   FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT location_id
          FROM locations
         ORDER BY your_spherical_cosine_law_distance_formula
         LIMIT 1
        ) AS one
   JOIN location_assignment AS la ON one.location_id = la.location_id
   JOIN profiles AS p on p.profile_id =la.profile_id
```

That should give you the appropriate list of profiles rows, without duplications.

You didn't ask about this, but I hope you don't have too many locations rows. The query you're using will necessarily scan through the whole table and do a lot of math for each row.  Your `HAVING` clause really doesn't help. To make this faster you need to combine a distance search with a bounding-rectangle search. This might help. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: This looks like it would work, and thank you very much for the optimization link! Things are very small at the moment but I bet this would have ended up biting me in the near future.

Comment: also hah sneaky looking up my coordinates ;)

Comment: I'm having some trouble synthesizing this optimization with the only-having-profiles-show-up-once thing, since doing the `ORDER BY` above would end up calculating the distance to every location. Using the subquery provided in the link, I get the locations in order of distance and can join them with profiles, but I can't seem to incorporate the logic of "only use a profile once, with the location at minimum distance". I can `GROUP BY` profile_id, but then I don't necessarily get the correct `location_id`

Comment: There must be something about your requirements or schema I don't get.  You want the single closest `locations` row, right? `LIMIT 1`? How does it turn into multiple `profiles` rows?

Comment: I'm wanting the list of every profile within, say, 50 miles of a given point, ordered by distance. The catch is that profiles may be associated with multiple locations (and multiple locations with each profile) and I only want a profile showing up once, associated with the location closest to the search origin. My current query is http://pastebin.com/Ph1A46Mx but it shows profiles multiple times if they are associated with multiple locations. Adding `GROUP BY profiles.profile_id` does not necessarily yield the closest `location` row (with the address etc)

Comment: This sounds kind of complex. It may involve a self-join on some table with a distance-based criterion. Hard to sort out without some tables with sample data.

Comment: Okay I *think* I got it: http://pastebin.com/pEqLsPFv
Would you mind taking a quick look and letting me know what you think? The bit I'm not too thrilled about is that I calculate the distance thing twice every time (I do all my calculations twice, and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` them together). Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add `MIN()` function to the distance calculation to get the distance to the closest location for each profile. Also, add `GROUP BY` to group by profile information.

(I know MySQL allows to return columns that are not in `GROUP BY` but this is not something I would recomment, so I removed `*` from your `SELECT`).

```
SELECT MIN(3959*acos(cos(radians(30.292424))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-  
       radians(-97.73856))+sin(radians(30.292424))*sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance,
      `profiles`.`name` as profilename, 
      `profiles`.`profile_id` as profile_id
 FROM (`profiles`)
 JOIN `location_assignment` 
          ON `profiles`.`profile_id` =`location_assignment`.`profile_id`
 JOIN `locations` 
          ON `location_assignment`.`location_id` = `locations`.`location_id`
GROUP BY `profiles`.`name`, `profiles`.`profile_id`
HAVING `distance` < 50
ORDER BY `distance`
LIMIT 3"
```

Comment: I believe that this would not give me the `locations` fields relating to the location with the minimum distance (the locations table has a variety of other information which I need to pull, and which needs to relate to the distance)

Comment: OK, if you do, the answer from Ollie Jones is better for you.